# I am using AndroidPdfViewer, is there any way to handle chapter or content

Tags: android, androidpdfviewer

I am using AndroidPdfViewer , is there any way to handle chapter or content.. like when clicked on content, it should open that only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No brother. There is no way to do like this. As we are building PDF dynamically from our code. So we have to follow some restrictions. We can't implement referring page. So so.

So enjoy and happy coding.

Rest you can ask about pdf creation. I will do help.

Comment: Thank you, brother, I also felt the same, now confirmed :)

Comment: Thanku soo much @anwar